# How to create two Foreign Key on pivot table linked to one Primary Key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, pivot-table

I'm trying to implement where I need to **insert** or **save** the current user that logged in. Inserting the recipient into user_id column works well but I need to manipulate who send the data I need to get the user id. I have two tables **users** and  **documents** with a pivot table **document_user**.

**users** table

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('remember_token');
 });
```

**documents** table

```
Schema::create('documents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**document_user** - pivot table

```
Schema::create('document_user',function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('document_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('document_id')->references('id')->on('documents')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->dateTime('dateReceived')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });
```

DB Design:

[image: DB]

> Note! I only insert few column in my **users** table migration just to save a line of text.

**Model**

User

```
public function documents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Document', 'document_user', 'user_id', 'document_id');
}
```

Document

```
public function recipients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'document_user', 'document_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Inserting records based on the user's choice to pivot table works well. But when I try to rollback my migration and alter my pivot table to this.

```
$table->integer('sender_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('sender_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

I get a error it says:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`webdev`.`document_user`, CONSTRAINT `document_user_sender_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`sender_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `document_user` (`document_id`, `user_id`) values (34, 10))
```

How can I achieve inserting the current user in my pivot table? So I can track who sends and receive the data. Any help would appreciated! Cheers!

**UPDATE 1:**

Thanks to @Dastur for solving my issue.

**document_user** table

```
Schema::create('document_user',function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('document_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('document_id')->references('id')->on('documents')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unsignedInteger('sender_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('sender_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');


        $table->dateTime('dateReceived')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });
```

I'm just having a hard time getting the id of the current user and insert this into `sender_id` column. Still don't have any idea to do this because I need to tracked the created documents of the users.

DocumentController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\Document;
use App\Models\User;
use DB;
use Auth;

class DocumentController extends Controller
{

public function getDocuments()
{
    //GETTING ALL THE ID OF THE USERS IN THE DATABASE EXCEPT THE ID OF CURRENT USER.
    $resultRecipient = DB::table('users')->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();


    //GETTING ALL THE CATEGORIES.
    $resultCategory = DB::table('categories')->get();

    //VIEW
    return view ('document.create')->with('resultRecipient', $resultRecipient)->with('resultCategory', $resultCategory);
}

public function postDocuments(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'title' => 'required|alpha_dash|max:255',
        'content' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'recipient_id' => 'required',
    ]);


    $document = new Document();
                                //Request in the form
    $document->title = $request->title;
    $document->content = $request->content;
    $document->category_id = $request->category_id;

    $document->save();
    $document->recipients()->sync($request->recipient_id, false);

    return redirect()->back();  
}

}
```

**UPDATE 2:** According to @Dastur I need to create a another Model for my pivot table which is `document_user`.

UserDocument (Model)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserDocument extends Model
{
protected $table = 'document_user';
}
```

Comment: migration does not insert in your table. you could use seeding!

Comment: @ClearBoth I think I cannot use seeding because it depends who the current user that logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked around a bit online, and found this post on laracasts: http://laravel.io/forum/09-18-2014-foreign-key-not-saving-in-migration. Also, this error is normally thrown when your trying to get a null value from another table and put it into a row that isn't nullable.

### Edit:

What your doing here is very strange, I still think the pivot table isn't a smart option. Here's exactly what I would do:

#### Migrations:

First, I would create my users migration, simple enough:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('username');
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
});
```

Next I would create my documents table:

```
Schema::create('documents', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('content');
    $table->integer('category_id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->integer('sender_id');
    $table->dateTime('dateRecieved')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

#### Models:

In your user and category model you need the following method:

```
public function documents() {
    $this->hasMany(/* Path to your document model */);
}
```

Finally, in your document model you need the following methods:

```
public function category() {
    $this->belongsTo(/* Path to your category model */);
}

public function user() {
    $this->belongsTo(/* Path to your user model */);
}
```

#### Document Controller

```
public function postDocuments(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'title' => 'required|alpha_dash|max:255',
        'content' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'recipient_id' => 'required',
    ]);

    /*
     * This part not exactly sure what to do, because of I don't know what
     * know what the difference is between the sender and the user, please
     * elaborate.
     */

}
```

Comment: I created a pivot table so I can track the created documents. Is it okay if I linked PK `users` table to FK in my `documents` table. Just to know who created the document?

Comment: I think it might have to do calling two rows "sender_id"

Comment: Where I'm gonna add this "sender_id" is it in the `documents` table? Because I need to track the created documents that's why I created a pivot table.

Comment: I elaborated my answer.

Comment: I get this error when I try to reference my PK in users table into user_id and sender_id in the pivot table. I'm trying to achieve to insert the current id user in my pivot table column `sender_id`

Comment: Edited again, hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: This works! But how can I determine the id of the current user? So I will able to insert this in my pivot table.

Comment: It's hard for me to say because I don't know what your doing in your application. Could you share your controller functions your using to handle saving your documents into the database?

Comment: Of course. Wait a minute I'll edit my post so you can fully see my controller.

Comment: Do you have a model for your document_user migration? You will need one.

Comment: I created a model for my `document_user` migration. What should I do next? Please see my post again :)

Comment: I edited again, but read the comment at the very bottom in the controller code block, it has a question.

Comment: your database design looks cool. But if I all reference this in my `documents` table. My `documents` table it's not already a master table. Because I don't want to move my master table. I planned to create a pivot table and reference all the to pivot table. So I can join them only by id.

Comment: I just don't think a pivot table is good in this situation, it overcomplicates all of the eloquent relationships. Also, [the offical docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships) is a good place to learn about eloquent relationships.

Comment: But do you think my db design is acceptable or not?

Comment: To be honest, no, because I think when using laravel you should try and use the methods it provides to make life easier, and the eloquent relationships make life so easy when it comes to relationships.